# Wavenumber Equation Confusion

Tags: waves, frequency, wavelength

I have spent a frustratingly large amount of time grappling with this equation for wavenumber but I still don't understand.

With the definition of wavenumber apparently being "the number of waves that fit in a unit distance" or something thereof, it seems appropriate that the equation should be $$k=\frac{1}{\lambda}$$

However it seems the equation is instead:
$$k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$$
I have tried many things to reason with myself to understand it but I just can't get over that fact that the first equation fits the definiton perfectly. I understand it is analogous to $$f=\frac{2\pi}{T}$$ for frequency, however in both cases I can't understand where the $2\pi$ comes from. Is it to do with the fact that $2\pi$ is equivalent to 1 full cycle of the circle which is 1 wavelength?

Comment: The wave vector $k$ actually represents the "phase advance per length". So one wavelength represents a phase advance of $2\pi$, so $k =\frac{phase\, advance}{length} = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$. BTW:  Frequency $f=\frac{1}{T}$, whereas the angular frequency $\omega = 2\pi f = \frac{2\pi}{T}$. The angular frequency is the same as the wave vector, but not in space, but in time:  "phase advance per time interval". As one period $T$ of time corresponds to a phase advance of  $2\pi$, so $\omega =\frac{phase\, advance}{time} = \frac{2\pi}{T}$.

Comment: A wave unit can have units of 'cycles' or 'radians' whether it be temporal or spatial. The $2 \pi$ factor just converts the units from cycles to radians.

Answer (score 1):

The first definition was used for a long time in spectroscopy. The second definition was introduced to simplify the description of the spatial periodicity of a sinusoid wave without an additional factor $2\pi$: $$\psi=\psi_0 exp(ikx)=\psi_0 exp(i \frac {2 \pi}{\lambda} x)$$ It is analogous to using the angular frequency $\omega=2\pi f$ instead of the frequency $f$ in a sinusoidal oscillation in time $$A=A_0 exp(-i\omega t)=A_0 exp(-i 2\pi f t)$$.